# How to collect data and put the content on the last page?

Tags: memory

I would like to collect some numbers into a list, and put the numbers on the last page, for example separated by comas.

Comment: Can you please add a full  [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you need to get your code to work (but don't add code that is not needed). This makes it much easier for people to help you. It would also be nice to know how you want to collect these "numbers" and what they are: are they page numbers, theorem numbers, ...? This will no doubt affect the solution.

Comment: The easiest way to use something like \edef\data{stuff} followed by \edef\data{\data,more stuff}

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way with `expl3` syntax (loaded via `xparse`), using `\addtolist` und `\showlist` automatically on the last page.

The `\addtolist` command even allows for specifying numbers itself in a comma separated list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_number_data_seq

\newcommand{\addtolist}[1]{%
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {%
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_number_data_seq {##1}%
  }
}

\newcommand{\showlist}{%
  \seq_use:Nn \l_number_data_seq {,~}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\AtEndDocument{%
  \clearpage
  \showlist%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\addtolist{20, 47}

\blindtext

\addtolist{35}
\end{document}
```